# Fill in Ansible template on a Windows system

Tags: python, windows, ansible, jinja2

I have a number of file templates that I'm deploying using Ansible and the `ansible.builtin.template` module. These are a bunch of JSON-files with Jinja-placeholders where variables are filled in. Default variable values are placed within a YAML-file called `defaults.yml`.

Now I've gotten the requirement to have the templates executed on the local system, which on Linux systems is not a problem running `ansible -e @defaults.yml localhost -m ansible.builtin.template -a "src=config.json.template dest=config.json"`.

The issue is with Windows systems. It's not really possible to run the Ansible client on a Windows machine besides having to fall back on Cygwin, WSL2 or Docker as far as I've learned from [this issue](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/issues/328). All of these aren't really options for me.

I've already checked whether I could run Jinja by itself, but that seems not to be that easy.

My question is if there's a way to fill in the templates without having to install a full Ansible client. Perhaps it's possible to run a templating submodule from Ansible or something similar?

Comment: Jinja is a python templating system, so, yes, it could most probably be used quite easily to achieve what you want: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#basics

Comment: Not without having to write my own script that uses Jinja. In retrospect I did not ask the question in the right way. I wanted to use a finished CLI solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there are several Jinja CLI packages available. I've tried a few and stuck with [j2cli](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli). Filling the templates is as easy as `j2 -f yaml -o config.json config.json.template defaults.yml`.

I also tried [jinja-cli](https://github.com/cykerway/jinja-cli), but found the documentation was lacking. With the docs from j2cli I was able to run my usecase successfully by executing `jinja -d defaults.yml -f yaml -o config.json config.json.template`.

Hope this helps someone with a similar issue.